# How to make a web page mobile?

Tags: mobile, html, meta-tags

Is there any specific html tag or meta tag that tells a web page is designed for mobile devices? I have created a mobile sitemap linking the mobile web pages, but I am afraid of search engines don't identify these webpages as mobile versions.

Comment: Do we talk about the appearance of the website? Because this is (or should be) controlled by css.

Comment: My main concern is how to have two different layouts, designs and volume of text exposed for the same webpage depending on the browsing device (if mobile or not). I created a m.domain.com site specific for mobile devices, and I am worried about search engines finding duplicate contents in there ...

Comment: all of the things you mention there, `layout`, `designs`, and `volume of text` can and should be controlled through CSS, with media queries.  plz sir use these. plzzz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Recommend using **[Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)** in your CSS and focusing on developing your mobile website first if you're going to use this technique.

Basic Example

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){
  //insert styles SPEFIC to resolutions greater than 480px wide
}
```

Regarding the comment:

```
//default CSS
.hidden-for-mobile{ display: none;}
//overrides the hidden style, and displays your element in larger resolution browsers.
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){
  display: inline; //or block or whatever you want 
}
```

*there may very well be a different or better way to implement this, but the point is...*

**If you are trying to control the look/feel of your website, do your best to keep it in the stylesheets**

**pro tip:** *You will want to use* `em / %` *based widths to ensure your site* responds *to your users browsers properly*

Check out a working example with HTML5 Boiler plate **[here](http://www.initializr.com/try)**.

And Media query browser support list **[here](http://html5please.com/)**

---

*Additionally*, if you are concerned about tracking your user base, **[Google Analytics](http://analytics.google.com/)** can do that for you.  You can break down your traffic however you'd like.

Comment: These media queries seem very useful to avoid duplicated content in mobile domains, but it's not enough for me because at mobile domain I constraint a lot the exposed contents, trying to preserve a reasonable proportion between screen area and volume of information.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. You can use JavaScript to detect mobile browsers, and direct users to special mobile versions of your webpages, but there is nothing that says for a specific page *this is for a mobile browser*.

If you are concerned that you will be presenting duplicate content to Google, block the spidering of your mobile site [via a robots.txt file](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93708), then ensure that mobile users are always redirected to the correct mobile site.

Comment: Yes, my concern is that precisely. I have a domain.com and a m.domain.com. I don't want the search engines find duplicated contents in mobile domain, because that could imply some kind of penalty to the search rankings. If I could explicit some way the pages at m.domain.com are specific for mobiles devices, I would feel better ...

Comment: @snippetsofcode OK - see updated answer. Block google from your mobile site.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about styles and things then see [How to setup HTML for mobile Devices with an header-image, that takes whole width of browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855237/how-to-setup-html-for-mobile-devices-with-an-header-image-that-takes-whole-widt)

Else, if you don't want search engines linking to m.domain.com instead of domain.com (or whatever) then I'd think about doing some PHP header detection to redirect to the main site.

To ensure they're not crawled at all so will never show in search results, add

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

Comment: I already have a redirect to avoid mobile devices remain at main domain. But what about search engine crawlers? Where do I redirect them? Main domain, mobile domain, or no redirection?

Comment: No redirection at all, if you don't want them to be crawled because you want everyone to be directed to the main site then add `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` to the mobile pages and they won't be indexed.